# Laravel get frequency from column

Tags: laravel, frequency

i need to get the most used code *(in example)* from a column. i try this code but this is not working.

```
$count = Invoice::with('userinvoicesubaccount')->where('person_id',$id)
        ->pluck('codeinvoice');
$count = array_count_values($count);
$count = array_keys($count);
$element = $count[0];
```

First i pluck list of all values.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get available 'distinct' codes
$distinct_codes = Invoice::select('codeinvoice')->where('person_id', $id)
            ->groupBy('codeinvoice')
            ->pluck('codeinvoice');

// a collection which will hold count of each code against the code
$code_counts = collect();

// for each code get the number of rows
// and add to the collection
foreach ($distinct_codes as $code) {

     $code_counts->push(collect([
         'code' => $code,
         'count' => Invoice::where(
              ['person_id', $id],
              ['codeinvoice', $code]
         ])->count()
     ]));
}

// get the most used code from that collection
$most_used_code = $code_counts->max->count;
```

Comment: thank u sir for ur interest, when i valid my url : www.host/fiche/{id} they attribute  0 -> $person_id and  $id -> $code . so i have sql error 
Should be : 
$id-> person_id

Answer (score 0):

In the case that `codeinvoice` is an attribute of the invoices table, you could do something like the following :

```
$count = Invoice::selectRaw('invoices.codeinvoice, count(invoices.codeinvoice) as ocurrences')
              ->where('person_id',$id)
              ->groupBy('codeinvoice');
```

For each returned row you'll have the code and the number of ocurrences of that code. Based on that, if you want just the most used, you could use `order by` and `limit` like this :

```
$count = Invoice::selectRaw(invoices.codeinvoice, count(invoices.codeinvoice) as ocurrences')
              ->where('person_id',$id)
              ->orderBy('ocurrences', 'desc')
              ->groupBy('codeinvoice')
              ->limit(1);
```

Then, the only one row returned will be the most used code.

I hope that's what you want.

Comment: hello sir, thank u for ur interest, i got error : Use of undefined constant invoices